# compare 2 strings while using dictionairies (anagrams)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Check if two strings are anagrams. Write a function anagrams(s1,s2), which given two strings s1 and s2, returns True if they are
anagrams, and False otherwise using dictionaries

1. if len(s1) different than len(s2) then they are not anagrams
2. i can't find a way to compare both strings using dictionaries.

Code:

```
D1={}
D2={}

def anagrams(s1,s2):
    if len(s1)!=len(s2):
        return False

    else:
         if D1==D2:
               return True
          else:
                return False
```

Comment: does your string contain spaces? what about special characters? Also I don't understand why you need a dictionaries.

Comment: Please help us and yourselve and formulate [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So far, there is none in you post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict for each string to count the number of occurrences of each distinct character:

```
def anagrams(s1, s2):
    d = {}
    for s in s1, s2:
        d[s] = {}
        for c in s:
            d[s][c] = d[s].get(c, 0) + 1
    return d[s1] == d[s2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dictionary, check the code below

```
def anagrams(s1,s2):
    s = s1+s2 #for example s = asd + dsa = asddsa
    l = list(s) #[a,s,d,d,s,a]
    dic = dict(enumerate(l)) # {0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'd', 3: 'd', 4: 's', 5: 'a'}
    if len(dic)%2 == 1: #if the two strings are anagrams, the length of the combined strings should be even number
        return False
    else: # now we just compare the two ends of all keys, in the above example, we compare 0 and 5 / 1 and 4 / 2 and 3
        # Notice: the sum of i and the its corresponding party is the len of dic
        i = 0
        while i < len(dic)/2:
            if dic[i] != dic[len(dic)-1-i]:
                return False
                break

            else:
                i += 1
        return True
```

Alternatively, you can use deque function, which satisfies the same purpose. The simple logic is to add the tow string together and compare the two ends

```
from collections import deque
def anagrams(s1,s2):
    s = s1+s2 # put them into one string and now we can simply compare if the far left and far right one is the same
    dq = deque(s) # apply deque function to it
    while len(dq) > 1: #if it equals to one
        if dq.popleft() != dq.pop():
            return False
    if len(dq) == 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load your words into a dictionary and compare the dictionaries' sorted values.

```
D1={}
D2={}

def anagrams(s1,s2):
    if len(s1)!=len(s2):
        return False

    else:
        elementNumber = 0
        for char in s1:                    #Load s1 into dictionary
            D1[elementNumber] = char
            elementNumber = elementNumber + 1

        elementNumber = 0
        for char in s2:                    #Load s2 into dictionary
            D2[elementNumber] = char
            elementNumber = elementNumber + 1

        print(sorted(D1.values()))         #Example output
        print(sorted(D2.values()))         #Example output

        if sorted(D1.values())==sorted(D2.values()): #Sort and compare
             return True
        else:
             return False

print("Anagrams: "+str(anagrams("Hello", "oHlel"))) #Returns True
print("Anagrams: "+str(anagrams("Hello", "xyzlo"))) #Returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just checking for an anagram try using python's `Counter` object. A single line is all you need.

From [anagram with Counter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anagram-checking-python-collections-counter/)

```
# Python code to check if two strings are 
# anagram 
from collections import Counter 

def anagram(input1, input2): 

    # Counter() returns a dictionary data 
    # structure which contains characters  
    # of input as key and their frequencies 
    # as it's corresponding value 
    return Counter(input1) == Counter(input2)
```